# How do i fix runtime error 7 Out of memory in an Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, out-of-memory

I'm working with a macro that compiles data from 3 different excel files into one file.
It always has run fine until today it stated flagging Runtime Error 7 out of memory. it gets hung up on line 132.

Unfortunately i did not create this macro, and to top it off I'm very unfamiliar with macros.
I've done some research into the error code and my virtual memory is set to recommended, nothing else is running on my computer except this macro. so the only other thing that came up in my research was 'LOOP'

there is a Loop at the point it gives the error but I've tried suggested fixes and non seem to work.

I'd like to know how to get around this if possible with some small edits to VBA code otherwise I have to kinda skip that line which then leaves me with an incomplete final file that i must now reference to the original 3 I started with. Below is the code the bold section is the line it gives the out of memory error.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

    With SnapDataTool.Sheets("Transcripts")
        .Activate
        lastRow = .Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Columns("A:E").Sort key1:=Range("A1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        
        For i = 2 To lastRow
                
                DoEvents
                SimpleStatus.updateTB.Caption = "Cleaning up the chat and email transcripts..." & vbCrLf & "Current Line: " & i
                DoEvents
                
                Do While .Cells(i, 1) = .Cells(i + 1, 1)
                    If .Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                        
                    **.Cells(i, 4) = .Cells(i, 4) & .Cells(i + 1, 4)**
                    .rows(i + 1).EntireRow.Delete
                    lastRow = lastRow - 1
                    
                Loop
        Next i
        
        DoEvents
        SimpleStatus.updateTB.Caption = "Finishing up transcript concatenation..."
        DoEvents
        
        .Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete
        .Columns(4).EntireColumn.Delete
        .Columns(3).WrapText = False
        
        DoEvents
        SimpleStatus.updateTB.Caption = "Concatenation complete..."
        SimpleStatus.Show vbModeless
        DoEvents
        
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code to see what happens?

Comment: The answer is no. and im not even sure how to do this. i have no clue about VBA or macors or even what to start with if im being honest.

Comment: Cell values are limited to a length of 32767 characters. If you are concatenating cell values and the length exceeds 32767, you will encounter this error. Although in my testing, VBA was able to continue without issues by discarding any characters exceeding the limit.

Comment: I’m not even sure I understand what you just said. I’m sorry. Not being rude just being thrown at something with little to no understanding.

Comment: Excel Cells can store text, but the text has to be shorter than 32767 characters. A character is a letter, number, space, or any symbol like !@#$%^&*(). You can type several paragraphs into an excel cell without hitting this limit of 32767. But if you were to type several pages of a novel into a single cell, you may encounter an error.

Comment: [How to step through code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/how-to/trace-code-execution)

Comment: Well i believe that is the issue as it is copying transcript in the specific cell, though the line it gets stuck on doesn't have anywhere near that amount of characters

Comment: Does the worksheet `Transcripts` have any event handlers in the worksheet code module?

Comment: My apologies but i dont understand the reference.

Comment: Right click on the tab for the sheet in question and choose "View code" - is there any code there, or is the code module empty?

Answer (score 0):

I 'm not sure this will solve the problem, but you could try this.
Omit the `For` loop and everything inside it. Replace it with this:

```
Range("A2") = WorksheetFunction.Concat(Range("A2:A" & lastRow))
Range("A3:A" & lastRow).EntireRow.Delete
```

As far as I understand, this will produce the same result.
I suggest that you tested it in **a copy** of your file though, not the original.